# Is it possible to make partial/selective search of documents in Solr/Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

Is it possible to search Solr/Elasticsearch (or some other solution) index without taking into account all documents?

Let's say I want to restrict an index of 50,000 documents to 5000 and search only this 5k?

A possible solution is to use solr core for each different subset but that would duplicate the documents. Is there any other solution without duplicating the documents?

Comment: Yes assuming you index the properties that allow you to distinguish these documents from the others, then you just need some filter(s) on top of your query, ie. (Solr) [fq (Filter Query) Parameter](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_3/common-query-parameters.html#fq-filter-query-parameter).

Comment: What is the reason for restricting the index to these 5k documents?

Comment: @MatsLindh Users are not supposed to search the whole index, only parts of it.

Comment: @EricLavault what kind of filters? Is this approach scalable ? (500k docs and they want to search within 50k ?) could you point to an example?

Comment: @DusanJ. You can force-apply a `fq` that limits the set of documents in your querying code in front of Solr if necessary. There are forks of Solr that provides document level authorization (such as Cloudera). There's a good discussion of possible options on the mailining list from back in 2014: https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/document-level-security-filter-solution-for-Solr-td4126992.html